# sedで複数条件による抽出方法

Tags: sed

（ファイル名）
sed_test.txt
（ファイル内容）
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd

```
sed_test.txt | sed -n '/c/p' > test.txt
```

test.txt
出力結果

3   cccc

やりたい事。
aaaaとccccを出力するという複数条件はどのようにするのでしょうか。
また、行番号も出力されるのですが、なしにできますか。

結果としては
aaaa
cccc
と出力したいです。

Comment: sed で行番号を付与するオペランドは `=` ですが、もしかして `cat -n` か `nl` コマンドを使用したのではないでしょうか？ `cat -n sed_test.txt | sed -n '/c/p' > test.txt`

Comment: cat コマンドcat sed_test.txtでファイルを表示するだけで、行番号が表示されます。恐らく以前、行番号を常に表示するようにしたと思うのですが、非表示にできますでしょうか？

Comment: `cat` がエイリアスされているのかもしれませんね。コマンドラインで `type cat` を実行すると何が表示されますか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。.bashrcにcat='cat -n'を設定しておりました。解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-e`オプションで複数のコマンドを処理させることができます。

```
cat test.txt | sed -n -e '/c/p' -e '/a/p'
```

なお、「マッチした行を抜き出す」のが目的であれば`grep`コマンドの方が適切(シンプルで簡単に出来る)かなと個人的には思います。